# Is there an way to preserve the sqlplus connection from shell script

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, sqlplus

In DB2, after connecting to DB, until and unless we are specifically use TERMINATE command, the connection keeps open and can be used for several sql execution using same connection inside a shell script. 
Is there any way to do the same in oracle sqlplus from shell script?

**For Example: bash script may look like below**

```
1. start of bash
2. sqlplus connection created
3. some bash commands
4. execute query using the same sqlplus connection created in 2nd step
5. some bash commands
6. execute query using the same sqlplus connection created in 2nd step
```

Comment: You can use the `HOST` command for step#3,5

Comment: It should be noted that the HOST command is often disabled as a security measure, so test in your environment to confirm.

Comment: @pmdba: how is disabling the HOST command a security measure? If someone can start sqlplus they can also simply exit sqlplus and run that command on the command line directly without the need to use HOST. Disabling the HOST command will not change anything

Comment: Thanks Everyone, that helped. HOST is working fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I understand it, there are situations in which users have the ability to run sqlplus as a part of some other script (embedded), but aren't supposed to have access it directly. Disabling HOST and certain other commands protects the system from a scenario where a user issues Ctrl+C during a report and accesses a SQL prompt inappropriately. The point is to make sure that sqlplus is only used for authorized activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help. I have found another solution which I think best suits my requirement and its working perfectly fine.
By accessing SQL*Plus using a Korn Shell Coprocess.
Below is an example I have run and it has given all results perfectly.

```
#!/bin/ksh
##

##

output=""                  
set -f output              

integer rc                
typeset -r ERRFILE=$0.err  
typeset -r EOF="DONE"      

## Create the error file or zero it out if it already exists.
> $ERRFILE

## Start sqlplus in a coprocess.
sqlplus -s connection |&

##  Exit SQL/Plus if any of the following signals are received:
##  0=normal exit, 2=interrupt, 3=quit, 9=kill, 15=termination
trap 'print -p "exit"' 0 2 3 9 15

## Send commands to SQL/Plus.
print -p "set heading off;"
print -p "set feedback off;"
print -p "set pagesize 0;"
print -p "set linesize 500;"

##
## Send a query to SQL/Plus.  It is formatted so we can set a shell variable.
##
print -p "select 'COUNT1='||count(*) as count from dual;"
print -p "prompt $EOF"  

while read -p output
do
   if [[ "$output" == "$EOF" ]]; then
     break
   else
     ## eval forces the shell to evaluate the line twice.  First, replacing
     ## "$output" with "COUNT1=99999", then again which creates and sets
     ## a variable.
     eval $output
   fi
done

##
##  Send another query to the same running sql/plus coprocess.
##
print -p "select 'COUNT1_DATE='|| sysdate as count_date from dual;"
print -p "prompt $EOF"
while read -p output
do
   if [[ "$output" == "$EOF" ]]; then
     break
   else
     eval $output
   fi
done

print -p "select 'COUNT2='||count(*)||';COUNT2_DATE='||sysdate from dual;"
print -p "prompt $EOF"
while read -p output
do
   if [[ "$output" == "$EOF" ]]; then
     break
   else
     eval $output
   fi
done


print -p "select count(*)||'|'||sysdate from dual;"
print -p "prompt $EOF"

while read -p output
do
   if [[ "$output" == "$EOF" ]]; then
     break
   else
     IFS="|"                      ## Set the Input Field Separator.
     set -A output_array $output  ## Create an array. It parses
                                  ## automatically on the IFS character.
   fi
done

print "COUNT1 count is $COUNT1"
print "COUNT1 date is  $COUNT1_DATE\n"
print "COUNT2 count is $COUNT2"
print "COUNT2 date is  $COUNT2_DATE\n"
print "Array count3:   ${output_array[0]}"
print "Array date3:    ${output_array[1]}"
```